# ASIHTTPRequest Post data from iPhone to PHP

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, asihttprequest

In Objective C I want to create a simple application that posts a string to a php file using ASIHTTPRequest.

I have no need for an interface and am finding it hard to find any example code. Does anyone know where I can find code, or can anyone give me an example of such code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ASIHTTPRequest documentation covers this.  Specifically, [Sending a form POST with ASIFormDataRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#sending_a_form_post_with_ASIFormDataRequest).

Answer (score 0):

[This site](http://www.webdesignideas.org/2011/08/18/simple-login-app-for-iphone-tutorial/comment-page-1/#comment-34811) has a really great walkthrough on how to use ASIHTTPREQUEST to authenticate data against a database. the walkthrough breaks the entire process down file by file for you.